# on click function to reveal hover overlay - appears on click but won't disappear on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, overlay

I have a portfolio grid of images and when a user hovers or taps on a mobile a transparent overlay with some text and a button appears

I am using the on click function

It works fine on my touch screen laptop but not on my iOS phone or tablet

The overlay appears on first tap, but when I tap again it does not disappear unless I tap another grid image.

I would like it to disappear on 2nd tap

I have tried various ways of making this work, and the closest I have got it for it to disappear when another grid image is tapped

Here is my code:
   **HTML**

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"><div class="image-wrap">
<div onclick="on()">
<img src="assets/images/pic.jpg">
<div class="overlay blue">
        <h3>Portfolio item 1</h3>
        <hr>
          <p><strong>Coming Soon</strong><br> some overlay text here</p>
          <br>
          <a href="contact-us" class="btn btn-white btn-lg">View Website</a>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

**CSS**

```
.image-wrap {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;  
}
.overlay {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color:white;
opacity: 0;
transition:opacity .5s ease-out;
text-align: center;
hr {
border: 1px solid #fff;
width: 10%;
 }

}

.image-wrap:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.red {
background: rgba(102,67,154,0.7);
}

.blue {
background: rgba(23,56,179,0.7);
}
.purple1 {
background: rgba(140,23,179,0.7);
}

.purple2 {
background: rgba(71,13,142,0.7);
}
}
```

I initially tried this with just CSS which gave me the desired result on all devices apart from iOS!

So I have decided to use the on click function to be more sure it works on all devices. I added the on click function to my existing code which I wrote to be used with CSS, but as I am rather new to JS I am wondering if I have it in the wrong place (the on-click)? I have tried lots of variations but this is the best I can get it to work

Any ideas of suggestions on how I can make the overlay disappear on the 2nd click would be great!

**js fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/49h450g9/14/

Please note: This works fine on touch-screen laptops, just not mobiles!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your functions **on** and **off** on jsfiddle example are not working at all. What happening is your hover effect on normal screen which as the behavior of mobile work like focus on mobile device.

Moreover, from your description here I believe that you have more than one portfolio on your project. So you have several element with the id **overlay** and multiple use of same id is not validate for html and also will cause JavaScript error.

To let your project work properly follow my list below:

- Make sure you have jQuery added on your project (generally before `</body>`)
- Now let us thinks of these portfolio item below

  ```
  <div class="portfolio">
      <img src="images/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="overlay">Link</div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio">
      <img src="images/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="overlay">Link</div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio">
      <img src="images/portfolio-3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="overlay">Link</div>
  </div>
  ```
- Then give the normal hover css styles inside media query like this. So that it never effect your js styles (I decide medias less than 992px as mobile device):

  ```
  .portfolio{
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      position: relative;
  }
  .portfolio .overlay{
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  @media all and (min-width:992px){
      .portfolio:hover .overlay{
          opacity: 1;
      }
  }
  ```
- Now with jQuery you can use event while user click any of the `.portfolio` item and toggle a class on it by which we will add further css to it:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      'use strict';

      $(.portfolio).on('click', function(){
          $(this).siblings('.portfolio').removeClass('hovered');
          $(this).toggleClass('hovered');
      });
  });
  ```
- Now it will add `hovered` class on 1st click and remove the `hovered` class on 2nd click. Also it will remove `.hovered` from other portfolio items. Now add the same css to it as the hover effect:

  ```
  .portfolio.hovered .overlay{
      opacity: 1;
  }
  ```

Comment: I thought this too but when I remove the hover code it doesn't work at all.. initially I removed both, yes I have a grid of images but was slimming the code down for the question. How would I go about fixing this issue? I tried without using an id (using just a class instead) and again it would not work.

Comment: And I have only used the id on one image btw, as I was just testing this new method..

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer. Let me know if you are facing any problem doing this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited my question last night as I continued working on this, I probably should have put a note! I will try out your solution and see how it works.. I may be mistaken but I thought the onclick functions were working on mobiles as when I took it out they didn't work but I am rather new to js..! Thanks so much i will try this and let you know how I get on, in the meantime I have upvoted you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("*").on("click, touchend", function(e) { $(this).focus(); });
```

or to achieve the opposite;

```
$("*").on("click touchend", function(e) { $(this).hover(); });
```

However the hover event doesn't work well on ios or other mobiles.

Another suggestion is to try replace any **css** using

`:hover with :active.`